# Getting error as Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture

Tags: angular, cordova, html5-video, cordova-plugins

We are having a cordova android app.We want to launch full screen for our custom html video player (video tag on orientation changed to 'landscape-primary').

We have used cordova-plugin-screen-orientation to detect screen.orientation.type and added below code

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",function()
{
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function()
{
console.log(screen.orientation.type); // e.g. portrait
if(screen.orientation.type == 'landscape-primary')
{
console.log(video);
video.webkitRequestFullscreen;
$scope.launchFullscreen();
}
if(screen.orientation.type == 'portrait-primary')
{
$scope.exitFullscreen();
}
//alert(screen.orientation.type);
});
})
```

> And used below launchFullscreen

```
$scope.launchFullscreen = function () {
      if(video.requestFullscreen) {
        parentdiv.requestFullscreen();
      } else if(video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        parentdiv.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if(video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
         fullScreenButton.style.display = "none";
         exitfullScreenButton.style.display = "inline-block";
         parentdiv.style.height = "100%";
         parentdiv.webkitRequestFullscreen();
         videoPlayer.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
          if(document.getElementById("custom-video-controls").style.display == "inline-block")
          {
            angular.element(document.getElementById("custom-video-controls").style.display="none");
          }
          else
          {
            angular.element(document.getElementById("custom-video-controls").style.display="inline-block");
          }
        }, false);
      }
    };
```

But we getting error as "Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture."

Also tried to programmtically trigger touchstart event but error pops up.
Let us know how we can achieve these??

Comment: I don't think browsers will allow you to do this. This is kind of a security issue. Forcing the user to go full screen without his interaction is not allowed.

Comment: @Amit how youtube mobile app achieved the same??Why it is not possible with cordova